# How to run emacsclient from applescript?

Tags: osx, emacsclient

I am using https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension which is a cool Chrome extension to capture links while browsing. The setup on OS X requires defining an Applescript application which is called by the extension. Here is the code I use:

```
on emacsclient(input)
    display dialog input
    try
        do shell script "/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-plus/25.2/bin/emacsclient -n '" & input & "'"
    on error e number n
        my logit("OOPs: " & e & " " & n, "Emacsclient")
    end try
end emacsclient

to logit(log_string, log_file)
    do shell script ¬
        "echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d %T: '`\"" & log_string & "\" >> $HOME/Library/Logs/" & log_file & ".log"
end logit

on open location input
    emacsclient(input)
end open location

on open inputs
    repeat with raw_input in inputs
        set input to POSIX path of raw_input
        emacsclient(input)
    end repeat
end open

on run
    do shell script emacsclient("")
end run
```

There is an Emacs running in daemon mode which is started upon initial login in the system. The problem I have is the emacsclient run in the script cannot find the server's socket: This socket is located inside my `$TMPDIR` which is set by OS X and is not available to scripts run through applescripts `shell script` action.

How can I solve this conundrum? I need either to run the daemon with a fixed socket file so that I can pass that to the client, or retrieve `$TMPDIR` from within applescript.

Comment: Run `do shell script "echo $TMPDIR"` in Script Editor gives the same output as in Terminal from here. Not sure why it didn't work for you.

Comment: FWIW, [Emacs Mac Port](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac) supports org-protocol out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @xuchunyang. Actually I did not even try `echo $TMPDIR`... I found another solution

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by looking for the actual socket file used:

```
on emacsclient(input)
    set socket to do shell script "lsof -c Emacs | grep server | grep -E -o '[^[:blank:]]*$' | head -1"
    try
        do shell script "/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-plus/25.2/bin/emacsclient -n '" & input & "' -s " & socket
    on error e number n
        my logit("OOPs: " & e & " " & n, "Emacsclient")
    end try
end emacsclient
```

@xuchunyang's solution would definitely be simpler though: `set socket to do shell script "echo $TMPDIR"`